# Enabling "Print as raster" option in QGIS Layout using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer

Can someone explain how to enable "Print as raster" option in layout properties using PyQGIS script.  I wanted to switch on with my Python script.

[image: 1]

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/e8ff03b0feda864f8613502d76cabe32350729c2/src/gui/layout/qgslayoutpropertieswidget.cpp#L243) it should be `layout.setCustomProperty("rasterize", True)`, where `layout` is a `QgsPrintLayout` object.

Comment: Add probably add something like `if layout.customProperty("forceVector"): layout.setCustomProperty("forceVector", False)` to ensure that both properties are not set to True (this is taken care of in the gui by unchecking/disabling checkboxes).

Comment: layout.setCustomProperty("rasterize", True) is working perfectly. Thank you team for quick help